# deploying rails application online

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment

what i know is i can create a rails application and run it locally. What i want to know is how to deploy it to the server.

now i have my rails application which runs locally, server with mysql and apache. I didn't have any scm

After i upload my application to the server and run "mysite.com"

it listed the directories and file of my rails application.

when i run  "mysite.com/public" i got "Welcome aboard" message in the browser and when i click "about your application's environment"
i got this,
**Not Found
The requested URL /public/rails/info/properties was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at softwaredevelopersus.com Port 80**

help me what i need to do to run it successfully?

Thanks,
arivarasan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [passenger](http://www.modrails.com/index.html) (aka mod_rails) to use a rails application with Apache. You need knowledge about Apache-configuration to get it working.

Also you need to have shell access to your server and the rights to configure it accordingly. Most root required.

Another way is to use hosters that specialised about rails like Railshoster.de or [heroku](http://www.heroku.com/).

Answer (score 1):

On top of passenger, we use capistrano and github together.

We work locally on a project, sync with git and then deploy to our webserver (apache on Ubuntu server 11).

Passenger is easy to install and set up if you're paying attention. Especially on Ubuntu.

In the office, we run passenger on a 10.6 server as webbrick's a bit slow, plus we have more than one app under development and it's easier to deal with virtual hosts rather than changing ports.

Follow this for capistrano, apache, passenger:

http://www.aaginskiy.com/technology/2011/02/deploying-rails-3-apps-with-capistrano/

There's a railscast for passenger on OSX here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/122-passenger-in-development

Comment: what i understand is congiuring the **config/deploy.rb** in my rails application and **virtualhost** in apache server will make my application runs

Comment: No specific need to edit config/deploy if you're using passenger. Just install it - sync your app to your server (using capistrano) and off you go. It's really easy. You'll need to modify your virtualhost file yes. Just make sure your path's right - without capistrano, you need to be in the public folder not the root of your rails app.